# UICollectionView: update flowLayout by pressing the button

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have two views. Parent view has content view which is `UICollectionView` and for example `UIButton`. How to change size (for example + 5px) of items  with pressing the button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have variable with collection view cell height and when click button increase this height then just reload collectionView and your cell will be higher

```
var CELL_HEIGHT = 44

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: CELL_WIDTH, height:CELL_HEIGHT)
}

@IBAction func buttonClick(sender: AnyObject) {
    CELL_HEIGHT = CELL_HEIGHT + 5
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: reloadData() didn't work for me. but I tried to set new UICollectionViewFlowLayout each time when value is changed... I'm not sure it's a good solution, but it works.

Comment: You need to call `invalidateLayout()` for the items to reread the heights

Comment: tank you! it's the best solution!